# How to connect using Putty to ubuntu in a virtual machine(VMWare)

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, putty

I can not connect to the virtual machine. I have read a lot of information, but it still does not work. Perhaps the problem is that when I prescribe in the console `ifconfig` I
[see that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm5XP.png)

In many examples, it says `eth1`, `eth0`, but I have a `ens33`. 
Also address from image doesn't ping (in CLI Windows). 
Virtual Machine settings is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YElkl.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8XfP.png). 
When I try connet from Putty to VM(input ip address and port. No more settings made) I show [this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQJUW.png).

I read a lot of answers from stackovwerflow, but most often answers is intall `openssh-server` (done), check port(done, it's 22), try in Ubuntu CLI `ssh -p22 user@localhost`(done, it's work). Also in Ubuntu CLI `service ssh status` (done, status enable)

Comment: This question belongs to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: In a Windows command prompt run `ipconfig /all | find /i "ipv4"` and show the results.

Comment: @AlexP 192.168.1.9

Comment: @AlexP and where I must insert it?(

Comment: In the question, of course. Also, please explain how the networking is set up. I understand that your host computer is 192.168.1.9, and the VM is 192.168.1.128. The host computer should have more than one IP address; one for the actual home/office network, and one for each VMware Virtual Network Adapter (the default installation makes two of those, VMNet1 and VMNet8). The VM can be configured for bridging to the actual home/office network, for NAT through the host, or for host-only networking.

Comment: @AlexP he has changed. Now he is 192.168.1.229. And when I type `ipconfig` it  do not have adapters for virtual machines

Comment: What VMware product are you using? That is, how do you run the virtual machine?

Comment: @AlexP VMware® Workstation 12 Pro. Just tap to green arrow

Comment: @AlexP and this IP address is wireless network adapter.

Comment: Your VMNet8 is wrong. Go to Virtual Network Editor, tap Restore Defaults.

Comment: @AlexP done. And what are the current network adapters now?

Comment: @AlexP and where I need to insert my ip address(that 192.168.1.229)?

Comment: You don't need to insert your host IP address anywhere. You should have both VMNet1 and VMNet8 (as shown in Virtual Network Editor and in Control Panel > ... > Network Connections) set to a 192.168.x.1, with 192.168.x different than your home network. You may want to find somebody near you who can help you hands-on.

Comment: ok, I set 2 adapter and it is the first - 192.168.2.0(VMnet1, host-only) and the second - 192.168.2.0(VMnet8, NAT). And when I write ifconfig in Ubuntu I see 192.168.3.128 address